# Halo: Reach and Call of Duty: Back Ops Controller mapping

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, halo-reach

Is it possible to have the same button/controller layout for Halo: Reach and Call of Duty: Black Ops?

I have a lot of experience with Reach and only started playing Black Ops. I am having difficulty switching between the controls and can't seem to find a common scheme which fits both!

Comment: Black Ops's controls are different on the PS3 than on the 360. What console do you use for Black Ops?

Comment: I use the xbox for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike most PC games, console games provide a number of different control configurations rather than allowing the user to bind specific actions to specific buttons.

I doubt it's possible to have the same control configuration on both games if you can't find them among the sets already provided.

Answer (score 1):

As Jasarien has already said, the controls are customised by choosing from the predefined options available, unlike on PC games which are usually completely customisable.

That said, Halo has the Green Thumb control scheme, which is the closest to Call of Duty available. Most notably it uses clicking the right stick for melee, but none of the options for the Halo controls include LT for aim down the sight.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy a modified controller, like Datel for example, that allows you to use CoD controls for Halo Reach. Even though the controller isn't as "ergonomic" or as high quality as the Microsoft ones, the upside is you can remap your controls by downloading a program on your PC, with rapid fire, etc. As for legality issues, I highly doubt you're going to get banned as you aren't illegally accessing data, hacking, etc. The rapid fire isn't even that useful either (I could spam the trigger faster). Another plus side is that you can get them at Walmart for like $30.